# Comparing Shor's and Regev's Quantum Factoring algorithm

Tags: quantum-computing, factoring, primes, integer-lattice

[Regev's factoring algorithm](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2308.06572.pdf) works as follows: (Say, for factoring integer $N$; input bitsize $n$).

**Step I:** Choose $a_1,\ ..., a_d$ *small* number (say, squares of first $d$ primes: (4, 9, 16, ...), where $d=\sqrt{n}$ (an optimal choice)). [Note-1: This choice paves the way for the speed-up.]

**Step II:** Now we solve the muti-dim period-finding problem for the function $f:(z_1,..,z_d)\rightarrow \prod_{i=1}^d a_i^{z_i} (mod N)$. [Note-2: Careful examination reveals why we only need to do repeated squaring for $\tilde{O}(n^{1.5})$].

**Step III:** Similar to the Shor algorithm, (a) use superposition (a Gaussian instead of uniform); (b) implement $f$ quantumly of step II; (c) use QFT for underlying abelian group.

**Step IV:** Now, we run the quantum circuit for $\sqrt{n}+4$ time (Corollary 4.2) and sample from the state vector. The LLL lattice reduction algorithm guarantees the finding of the period vector with a probability of at least 0.5.

Now, I am trying to relate some of the features of Shor's algorithm to Regev's algorithm.

In Shor's, during the sampling part, it relies on the co-primality fact, i.e., $\phi(r)/r\approx \frac{1}{loglog(r)}$, thus repeat the quantum circuit for $O(loglog(r))$. This also paves the way for the recovery of the period via continued fraction.

I see Regev's algorithms as a d-dimensional generalization of Shor's algorithms (1-dim problem).

> Can we find the counterpart of co-primality (CP) and continued fraction (CF) in Regev's approach? Or it bypasses these requirements at all.

My intuition behind the question: I sense Regev's algorithm **might be** generalizing the CP and CF in some way. I suspect the LLL algorithm might be hiding them into its details.

**Note**: The LLL algorithm can be seen as a generalization of GCD as per [this](https://www.di.ens.fr/%7Epnguyen/SLIDES/SlidesLuminy2010.pdf). I can see GCD as a test of co-primality. Still, I am expecting to see the connection more explicitly.

I would highly appreciate some pointers in the comment section, too.

Comment: What is the coprimality and CF analogy?

Comment: @Turbo, thanks. I have rephrased it to be more precise about the 'CF analogy' statement.